# How to require multiple roles/authorities

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-4

As far as I can tell only *any of* lists are available in `@Secured` annotations or `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer` objects. Trying to add multiple annotations or `hasAuthority()` calls either fails to compile or only the latest one is used.

How can I define that a particular request (set of requests matching a pattern), or method requires *all of* a list of roles/authorities?

Comment: `hasAuthority() and hasAuthority() and hasAuthority()` for `@Secured` and `access()` when using the `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer`.

Comment: You mean `@PreAuthorise`, not `@Secured`?

Comment: The problem with that is there's no way to add to the SpEL context, so you can't use constants specifying the names.

Comment: Well no,but why would you want a constant?

Comment: Why does anyone want hard-coded strings used in multiple places in constants? For reduced bugs and better maintainability.

Comment: And how would that lead to less bugs, you would need the same amount of static references as roles.

Comment: You can't spell it wrong, for example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best solution appears to be

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('one') and hasRole('two') and ...")
```

There's no nice way to use constants, like with `@Secured`.

Comment: In my project I use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`, and this works for authorities as well (just change Role for Authority):

`@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('one') and hasAuthority('two') and ...")`

For any of you can change `and` for `or`

Comment: @Ernani `hasRole('x') <=> hasAuthority('ROLE_x')`

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be using: `hasAuthority([authority])`. This only takes one authority. Instead use `hasAnyAuthority([authority1,authority2])`. This allows you to specify multiple authorities at once and any can be considered in authorization. Reference official spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/). Just find in page the text: `hasAnyAuthority([authority1,authority2])`

For example on your controller method, add: `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('permission1','permission2')")`

Comment: As stated in the question, that's *any of*, not *all of*.

Answer (score 4):

From Spring Security 5.8, Spring has provided support for [AuthorizationManager composition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11625) with the `AuthorizationManagers` class.

With this, we can define the `HttpSecurity` as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
          .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/my-endpoint")
            .access(AuthorizationManagers.allOf(
              AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority(("SCOPE_one")),
              AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("SCOPE_two")))
          .anyRequest()
            .authenticated());
    return http.build();
}
```

Of course, make use of static imports to present the configuration in a cleaner manner, I included the classes here for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

As an endpoint-wide solution, you can just use

```
.antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasAuthority('AUTHORITY_1') and hasAuthority('AUTHORITY_2')")
```

I only tested it with two authorities, but I suppose you can and- more than two.

Comment: It seems with the new `authorizeHttpRequests`, there is no `access` method that supports passing a String as param

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Security 5.5 you can use a custom `AuthorizationManager` when using the `AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer`.

```
public class DelegatingMultiAuthorizationManager<T> implements AuthorizationManager<T> {
    private final List<AuthorizationManager<T>> authorizationManagers;

    public DelegatingMultiAuthorizationManager(List<AuthorizationManager<T>> authorizationManagers) {
        this.authorizationManagers = authorizationManagers;
    }

    public static <T> DelegatingMultiAuthorizationManager<T> hasAll(AuthorizationManager<T>... authorizationManagers) {
        Assert.notEmpty(authorizationManagers, "authorizationManagers cannot be empty");
        Assert.noNullElements(authorizationManagers, "authorizationManagers cannot contain null values");
        return new DelegatingMultiAuthorizationManager(Arrays.asList(authorizationManagers));
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, T object) {
        for (AuthorizationManager<T> authorizationManager : authorizationManagers) {
            AuthorizationDecision decision = authorizationManager.check(authentication, object);
            if (decision == null || !decision.isGranted()) {
                return new AuthorizationDecision(false);
            }
        }

        return new AuthorizationDecision(true);
    }
}
```

This AuthorizationManager requires each provided AuthorizationManager to grant access. If any of them does not grant access the authorization will fail.

You can then use it like this (which also allows using constants):

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .antMatchers("/something/*")
                .access(DelegatingMultiAuthorizationManager
                                .hasAll(AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("auth_a"),
                                        AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("auth_b")))
```

Comment: I assume that doesn't work in annotations though?

Comment: No, as others have said you can use `hasAuthority(..) and hasAuthority(..)` for annotations. If you want to further use constants in your annotations you'd need to either use the full name (for example `hasAuthority(T(com.my.package.Constants).AUTH_A)`) or use a bean reference (for example `hasAuthority(@bean.AUTH_A)`)

Answer (score -3):

You can use `hasAnyAuthority` as like `.hasAnyAuthority("manager", "customer");`